# How to bound the tail of p-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

How can I asses $S_n = \sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac{1}{j^p}, p>1$ in terms of $n$, specifically can I get something like $$S_n = O(?)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the fact that for any decreasing function $f$
$$
\int_{s=a}^{b+1} f(s)\mathrm ds \le \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i) \le \int_{s=a-1}^{b} f(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
We obtain that
$$
\frac{n^{1-p}}{p-1}\le\sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac1{j^{p}}\le\frac{(n-1)^{1-p}}{p-1}.
$$
since $p>1$. Hence,
$$
\sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac1{j^{p}}=O(n^{1-p})
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac{1}{j^p}
= n^{-p+1} \times \frac 1n \sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac{n^p}{j^p}
\sim n^{-p+1} \int_1^\infty \frac {du}{u^p} = n^{-p+1}\frac 1{p-1}
$$